# Why ReadOnlyCollection<T> is not ReadOnlyCollection<out T>?

Tags: c#, generics

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` supports only reading operations. Why `T` is not marked with `out` keyword?

Comment: Classes cannot mark type parameters with `in` or `out`.

Comment: 1) the interfaces, such as `IList<T>`, it implements are not co-variant(apart from `IEnumerable<T>`) since MS designed them badly in .net 2.0. 2) Classes can't be co-variant.

Comment: @HansPassant How is that relevant to co-variance? `IEnumerable<T>` and the new `IReadOnly...` interfaces don't promise that either, and still they're co-variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ReadOnlyCollection supports only reading operations

It only supports reading because is a base class for a generic read-only collection.

> Why T is not marked with out keyword?

out keyword indicates that the parameter is covariant and only interfaces and delegates can be covariant. Note that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant.